# Use the RSolve command of Mathematica to solve difference equations in matrix form？

Tags: matrix, difference-equations

For example, if $A$ is a matrix, the following is its difference equation representation.

How can I rewrite the code to use the **RSolve** command correctly?

```
A = {{0, -1/0.2}, {1/0.01, -1/(22 0.01)}};
RSolve[{A[n + 1] - 2 A[n] == 1, A[0] == 1}, A[n], n]
```

Comment: You can not define the variable  A={...}  that you are searching.

Comment: @DanielHuberan Can $RSolve$ command solve the difference equation in matrix form？

Comment: @chenchen The matrix difference equation should be `A[n + 1] - 2 A[n] == IdentityMatrix[2]` I think

Comment: @chenchen You got answer to this question some days ago: [Matrix difference equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280087/matrix-difference-equation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) `A[0]`

```
A[0] = {{0, -1/0.2}, {1/0.01, -1/(22 0.01)}} // Rationalize;
```

Define `A[n]` recursively

```
A[n_Integer?Positive] := A[n] = 2*A[n - 1] + IdentityMatrix[2]
```

Generate a sequence of matrices

```
MatrixForm /@ (seq = (A /@ Range[10]))
```

[image]

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) for each matrix position to find the general solution

```
(A2[n_] = Partition[
     FindSequenceFunction[#, n] & /@
      Transpose[Flatten /@ seq],
     2] // Simplify) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comparing the general solution with the recursive definition over a broader range

```
And @@ Table[A[n] == A2[n], {n, 0, 100}]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** For a general 2x2 initial matrix

```
Format[a[n__]] := Subscript[a, Row[{n}]]

\[DoubleStruckCapitalA][0] = Array[a, {2, 2}];

\[DoubleStruckCapitalA][n_Integer?Positive] := 
  \[DoubleStruckCapitalA][n] = 
  2*\[DoubleStruckCapitalA][n - 1] + IdentityMatrix[2]

seq = (\[DoubleStruckCapitalA] /@ Range[7]) // Simplify;

(\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]2[n_] = 
   Partition[FindSequenceFunction[#, n] & /@ 
    Transpose[Flatten /@ seq], 2] // Simplify) // 
    MatrixForm
```

[image]

Verifying that the general solution agrees with the recursive definition over a broad range

```
And @@ Table[\[DoubleStruckCapitalA][n] == 
  \[DoubleStruckCapitalA]2[n], {n, 0, 100}] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comparing with the initial result,

```
repl = Thread[
  Flatten[\[DoubleStruckCapitalA][0]] -> 
   Flatten[Rationalize[{{0, -1/0.2}, {1/0.01, -1/(22 0.01)}}]]]
```

[image]

```
A2[n] === Simplify[\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]2[n] /. repl]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Using [`RSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolveValue.html) indirectly

```
RSolveValue[{A[n + 1] - 2 A[n] == 1, A[0] == A0}, A[n], n]

(* -1 + 2^n + 2^n A0 *)
```

Converting this result to matrices

```
A0 = Array[a, {2, 2}];

(A[n_] = 2^n*A0 + 2^n*IdentityMatrix[2] - IdentityMatrix[2]) // 
  MatrixForm
```

[image]

This is identical to \[DoubleStruckCapitalA]2[n]